# How To Send Email by Microsoft Outlook Using oauth in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email, oauth, office365

I have been using outlook for sending emails as they have removed basic autentication so we are moving to modern authentication i have used the following api end point to get the access token
https://login.microsoftonline.com/##############/oauth2/v2.0/token

and i have received the access token.
following is the mail.php settings

`driver => 'smtp', 'host' => 'smtp-mail.outlook.com', 'port' => 587, 'from' => array('address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS'), 'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Laravel')), 'encryption' => 'tls', 'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),`your text `'password' => ACCESS TOKEN,`your text `'pretend' => false,`

When i am sending the email using laravel default Mail function it gives me following error
exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "##############" using 2 possible authenticators. If i turn on the basic authentication email is sent successfully but it is not working with oauth.I have tried everything to solve the issue but did not found any documentation for help